# Complete Set of Propositional Formulas (Different Definition)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory

**P.S. I solved the problem, my instructor admitted that there is a typo in the definition of completeness. The set $P$ should be $Fml_P$.**

The following is an exercise about compactness in propositional logic. (This is from the book *A First Journey through Logic*.)

> Let $Fml_P$ be the set of propositional formulas over an infinite set
> $P$ of propositional variables. A set $\Sigma \subseteq Fml_P$ is
> called *satisfiable* if there is an assignment $\delta : P \rightarrow
> > \{0,1\}$ such that $\delta^*(F)=1$ for all $F\in \Sigma$; it is called
> *finitely satisfiable* if every finite subset $\Sigma_0 \subseteq \Sigma$ is satisfiable.
>
> The aim of this exercise is to prove the following result: *A set
> $\Sigma \subseteq Fml_P$ of propositional formulas is satisfiable if
> and only if it is finitely satisfiable.*
>
> (1) Prove the theorem in the special case when $\Sigma$ is complete,
> that is, **when for every $p\in P$ one has $p\in \Sigma$ or $\neg p
> > \in \Sigma$**.
>
> (2) Prove that every finitely satisfiable set of propositional
> formulas is contained in a finitely satisfiable set which is complete.
>
> (3) Conclude.

Since this is my homework, I don't want to answer, of course. However, I'm not sure about the definition of completeness. I can prove completely if I take the definition of completenes as follows: **when for every $p\in Fml_P$ one has $p\in \Sigma$ or $\neg p \in \Sigma$**. The book assumed this for only propositional variables. I wonder if this definition is right, or not. Also, I wonder if it is possible to extend this to all propositional formulas (maybe inductively). If someone share an idea about that, it would be really helpful.

Let me share the related definitions, too.

> One fixes a set $P = \{p_i | i ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$, where the $p_i$ are
> called *propositional variables* (they will take only “true” or
> “false” as values). *Propositional calculus formulas* are defined as
> words over the alphabet $P \cup \{\neg, \land ,( ,)\}$, formed
> according to the following rules:
>
> • $p_i$ is a formula for any $i$;
>
> • if $F$ and $G$ are formulas, then $\neg F$ and $(F\land G)$ are
> formulas, too.
>
> Let $Fml_P$ denote the set of propositional calculus formulas. As
> before we introduce the abbreviations $\lor , \rightarrow,
> > \leftrightarrow$.
>
> One identifies $\mathbb{Z}/2 = \{0, 1\}$ with { “false”, “true”}, by
> assigning 0 to “false” and 1 to “true”.  An *assignment* is a function
> $\delta : P \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Any assignment $\delta$ induces a
> function $\delta^*: Fml_P \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ defined by
> $\delta^*(p_i) = \delta (p_i), \delta^*(\neg F) = 1−\delta^*(F)$ and
> $\delta^*(F \land G) =\delta^*(F)·\delta^*(G)$ , inductively.

Comment: The set you are describing would be maximally consistent, that is $\Sigma \not\vdash \bot$ would hold and there would be no larger consistent set of formulas containing $\Sigma$, the set your course is describing is not maximally consistent, but it is consistent, and they are asking you to consider it so as to provide you with a hint as to what valuation to define to show $\Sigma$ with all propositional variables (xor their negations) is satisfiable. A hint is to consider what valuation would be needed in this case, certainly it would need to value the propositional variables in $\Sigma$ true.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the map $\delta : P \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ defined by $\delta(p)=1 \leftrightarrow p \in \Sigma$ should work. It is well-defined by the consistency. I tried to show if $F\in \Sigma $, then $\delta^*(F)=1$ inductively. However, I have no control over the case $F=G\land H$, or I did something wrong.

Comment: I see, I think I understand why you want to extend to a maximally consistent set, as if $\Sigma$ were maximally consistent, then the inductive step would be easy, you could just say $\delta^{\ast}(G) = 1$ necessarily because $\neg G$ is not in $\Sigma$, so $G$ is, and the same for $H$, without extending to a maximally consistent set it seems a little trickier.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I think that there may be a mistake in this definition. I don't know how to deal with this. I also checked if there is an errata for the book, but there isn't.

Comment: @porridgemathematics I asked my instructor, and he said that there is a typo here. The set $P$ in the definition of completeness should be $Fml_P$. Thanks for your interest.